# Passing C# byte[] to a VARBINARY SQL field

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with a field declared as VARBINARY (8000)

A stored procedure is used to write to this table, and it takes a parameter of VARBINARY (8000)

The C# code calls the stored procedure passing in a byte[] as this parameter.

In certain circumstances a SQL exception is thrown because the field is too large.

This will seem like a simple question but so far I have been unable to find an answer

How large can my byte[] be to not overflow the SQL field?

Comment: Can you post some codes?

Comment: If the field is declared as `VARBINARY(8000)`, then the obvious answer is "it can be 8000 bytes or less" - are you seeing something different?

Comment: Yes I am,  one example I am seeing failing is taking in a byte[] of 3262 in length and an exception is thrown

Comment: @JDibble that should work fine; I *think* we'd need to see a few things here - most specifically the **EXACT** error message, and an indication of whether it is coming from sql-server or .net; and some of the code that is manipulating it. For example, is it possible that some code like a trigger or index is using it?

Comment: Firstly this is code that I am supporting, not something I have written.  I has assumed that 8000 bytes would be the limit, but in practice this seems not to be the case  Exception is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: @Mark Gravell.  The issue was being caused by a trigger on the table.  The work done by the trigger was causing the truncation error.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a SQL Server 2008 table with a field declared as VARBINARY (8000)

...

> How large can my byte[] be to not overflow the SQL field?

This *feels* like a trick question, but the "obvious" answer here is: 8000 bytes.

Comment: The issue was being caused by a trigger on the table, not by the data being written to the table itself.  It did look like and "idiot" question but was a real problem in a live system.

Answer (score 0):

Your byte[] can be a maximum of 8000 to not overflow the field.

Answer (score 0):

Its 8000 in your case but why not use the maximum allowed size using `VARBINARY(MAX)` this will be capable of storing  2^31-1 bytes, see [binary and varbinary on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Re-sizing is not a solution,  changing from varbinary(8000) to varbinary(max) will result in a loss of the existing data.  This cannot happen - so I am stuck with the database definition

Comment: @JDibble SQL Server will do an in place conversion, as a transaction, so i would not expect any dataloss.

Comment: That's not what the DBAs say here :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem caused by a trigger on the table.  The work done by the trigger was throwing the exception.  It was nothing to do with data being written to the table.

Thanks all or your help